# R: Tidyverse - Merging only the duplicate columns in a tibble

Tags: r, tidyverse, tibble, summarize

Some columns of my tibble are torn into two columns. I would like to merge them back together. The duplicate columns have the same name and read_delim() adds "...2" and "...3" to have identical column names. There shouldn't be two numerical values in a duplicate column, but it would be nice, if the code could handle this exception (there the mean of both would be nice). It frequently occurs, that both duplicate columns contain NAs. Some columns occur only once (like Date&Time, PYRANO#1, ...). "Date&Time" is the only consistent column without NAs.

The data looks like this:

```
head(df)

A tibble: 6 × 10

  | ------------------- | ------------------- | ------------------ | -----------------
  | `Date&Time`         |`SNOWDEPTH#1#HS...2` |`SNOWDEPTH#1#HS...3`| `PYRANO#1#RSWR…`
  | <dttm>              |               <dbl> |           <dbl>    |        <dbl>
  |:-------------------:|:-------------------:|:------------------:|:----------------- 
1 | 1997-11-19 16:30:00 |                   0 |               NA   |            NA
2 | 1997-11-19 17:00:00 |                  NA |               10   |            NA
3 | 1997-11-19 17:30:00 |                   9 |               NA   |            NA
4 | 1997-11-19 18:00:00 |                  NA |               NA   |            NA
5 | 1997-11-19 18:30:00 |                   9 |               NA   |            NA
6 | 1997-11-19 19:00:00 |                   9 |               NA   |            NA

# with 6 more variables: `MODEL_SNOWPACK#1#SWE` <dbl>,
#   `THERMO_HYGRO#1#TA_30MIN_MEAN...6` <dbl>,
#   `THERMO_HYGRO#1#TA_30MIN_MEAN...7` <dbl>,
#   `IRTHERMO#1#TSS_30MIN_MEAN...8` <dbl>,
#   `IRTHERMO#1#TSS_30MIN_MEAN...9` <dbl>,
#   `SNOWTHERMO#1#TS0_30MIN_MEAN` <dbl>
```

I would like to use a for-loop to loop through many of these files, but unfortunately the duplicate columns aren't always the same. Ideally the code should find duplicate columns and merge them automatically.

What I have tried so far:

```
substr(colnames(df), 1, 7)
```

> [1] "Date&Ti" "SNOWDEP" "SNOWDEP" "PYRANO#" "MODEL_S" "THERMO_" "THERMO_"
> [8] "IRTHERM" "IRTHERM" "SNOWTHE"

```
df %>% 
      group_by(., substr(colnames(.), 1, 7), na.rm=TRUE) %>% 
      summarise_all()
```

Error in `group_by()`:
! Problem adding computed columns.
Caused by error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = substr(colnames(.), 1, 7)`.
✖ `..1` must be size 407400 or 1, not 10.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution is to turn it into a long format, remove the "..." (etc.) and then transform it back to wide format with a function:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df |>
  pivot_longer(-date) |>
  mutate(name = str_remove(name, "\\.\\.\\.\\d")) |>
  pivot_wider(values_fn = ~ mean(., na.rm = TRUE))
```

Output:

```r
# A tibble: 6 × 2
   date `SNOWDEPTH#1#HS`
  <int>            <dbl>
1     1                0
2     2               10
3     3                9
4     4              NaN
5     5                9
6     6                9
```

And some data:

```r
df <- tibble(date = 1:6,
             `SNOWDEPTH#1#HS...2` = c(0, NA, 9, NA, 9, 9),
             `SNOWDEPTH#1#HS...3` = c(NA, 10, NA, NA, NA, NA))
```